# How does Particle Swarm Optimization reach a final solution?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, particle-swarm

I understand that each particle is a solution to a specific function, and each particle and the swarm is constantly searching for the best solution. If the global best is found after the first iteration, and no new particles are being added to the mix, shouldn't the loop just quit and the first global best found be the most fitting solution? If this is the case what makes [PSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) better than just iterating through a list.

Comment: As far as I know, you never know if you have reached a **global** solution. Verifying this would require enumerating a number polynomial in the number of solutions.

Comment: From my understanding, at every iteration a particle will move towards the current best solution (either locally or globally). If you don't know the current best solution wouldn't the particle just move randomly and not swarm towards anything making the whole process useless?

Comment: Indeed, the **current best** solution. But your question asks something about the **global** solution. And it is impossible to efficiently determine if you reached the global optimum.

Comment: That is bad wording on my part. An example might clear up what I am trying to ask. Say there were 20 particles. PSO runs its first iteration and a current best solution is found. Wouldn't that be the best solution possible out of all of the particles and we can quit PSO there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your terminology is a bit off.  Simple PSO is a search for a vector x that minimizes some scalar objective function E(x).  It does this by creating many candidate vectors.  Call them x_i.  These are the "particles".  They are initialized randomly in both position and rate of change, also called velocity, which is consistent with the idea of a moving particle, even though that particle may have many more than 3 dimensions.

Simple rules describe how the position and velocity change over time. The rules are chosen so that each particle x_i tends randomly to move in directions that reduce E(x_i).

The rules usually involve tracking the "single best x_i value seen so far" and are tuned so that all particles tend to head generally toward that best value with random variations. So the particles swarm like buzzing bees, heading as a group toward a common goal, but with many deviations by individual bees that, over time, cause the common goal to change.

It's  unfortunate that some of the literature calls this goal or best particle value seen so far "the global minimum." In optimization, global minimum has a different meaning. A global minimum (there can be more than one when there are "ties" for best) is a value of x that - out of the entire domain of possible x values - produces *the* unique minimum possible value of E(x).

In no way is PSO guaranteed to find a global minimum.  In fact, your question is a bit nonsensical in that one generally *never knows* when a global minimum has been found.  How would you?  In most problems you don't even know the gradient of E (which gives the direction taking E to smaller values, i.e. downhill). This is why you are using PSO in the first place.  If you know the gradient, you can almost certainly use numerical techniques that will find an answer more quickly than PSO.  Without a gradient, you can't even be sure you've found a *local* minimum, let alone a global one.

Rather, the best you can usually do is "guess" when a *local minimum* has been found.  You do this by letting the system run while watching how often and by how much the "best particle seen so far" is being updated.  When the changes become infrequent and/or small, you declare victory.

Another way of putting this is that PSO is used on problems where reducing E(x) is always good and "you'll take anything you can get" regardless of whether you have any confidence that what you got is the best possible.  E.g. you're Walmart and any way of locating your stores that saves/makes more dollars is interesting.

With all this as background, let's recap your specific questions:

> If the global best is found after the first iteration, and no new particles are being added to the mix, shouldn't the loop just quit and the first global best found be the most fitting solution?

There's no answer because there's no way to determine a global best has been found.  The swarm of buzzing particles might find a new best in the next iteration or ten trillion iterations from now.  You seldom know.

> If this is the case what makes PSO better than just iterating through a list?

I don't exactly grok what you mean by this.  The PSO is emulating the way swarms of biological entities like bugs and herd animals behave.  In this manner it resembles genetic algorithms, simulated annealing, neural networks, and other families of solution finders that use the following logic:  Nature, both physical and biological, has known-good optimization processes. Let's take advantage of them and do our best to emulate them in software.  We are using nature to do better than any simple iteration we might devise ourselves.

Comment: About "iterating through a list": if it means iterating through every possible combination, that's unrealistic due to [the size of the search space](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/27/IsTheSearchSpaceOfAnOptimizationProblemReallyThatBig.html) for NP-complete or NP-hard problems.

Answer (score 0):

Given a function, a particle swarm attempts to find the solution (a vector) that will minimize (or sometimes maximize, depending on the problem) the value to that function.

If you happen to know the minimum of the solution (suppose for argument sake, it is 0) AND
if you are lucky enough to generate the solution that gives you 0 on the first step, then you can exit the loop and stop the algorithm.

That said; the probability of you randomly generating that solution on initialization is **infinitely** small.

In most practical terms, when you would want to use a PSO to solve, it is most likely that you will not know the minimum value, so you wont be able to use that as a stopping condition.

The particle swarm optimization, the optimization process is not in the way the random initial step occurs, but rather the modification that occurs by adapting the initial solution with the velocity determined by social and cognitive component.

- The **social component** consists of the current evaluated global best solution of the swarm
- The **cognitive component** consists of a the best location seen by the current solution.

This adjustment will move the particle along a line between the global best and the current best - in hope there is a better solution between them.

I hope that answers the question in some way

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some piece in answering, your problem seems to be linked to the common issue of "when should I stop my PSO?" A question everyone is faced when launching a swarm since (as clearly explained above) you never know if you reached the global best solution (except in very specific objective functions).

Usual tricks already present in most PSO implementation:
1- just limit a number of iterations since there is always a limit in processing time (and you could implement different ways to convert the iterations number into a time limit by self assessment of time spent to evaluate the objective).
2- stop the algorithm when the progress in optimization starts to be insignificant.